# What is the explanation for a Blazor reference starting with a tilde? "~/(...)"

Tags: c#, blazor

What is the explanation for a Blazor reference starting with a tilde? "~/(...)"

This can be found in _Hosts.cshtml file:

```
<link href="~/css/Chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What is the exact meaning of "~"? What is the difference to just "/" or without?

Is it important to (not) use "~" if you refer to an external library?

I could not find an explanation for this.

Comment: [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#web-root): *In Razor .cshtml files, tilde-slash (~/) points to the web root. A path beginning with ~/ is referred to as a virtual path.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Razor .cshtml files, tilde-slash (~/) points to the web root.

The default web root is wwwroot.

> A path beginning with ~/ is referred to as a virtual path.

The Tilde Slash is a feature of Razor, which converts a relative path to an absolute. Thus, the path for the href in `<link href="~/css/Chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />` will be converted to an absolute path like this:

```
<link href="/css/Chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Note that the _Hosts.cshtml file contains the the *base* element like this:

```
<base href="~/" />
```

The "~/" is a relative path, and it is converted to `<base href="/" />`

The base URL is used to resolve relative URLs when the NavigationManager needs to obtain an absolute URL.

> Is it important to (not) use "~" if you refer to an external library?

If by *external* you mean external to the  Blazor App space, I guess you shouldn't use the tilde-slash feature at all. You should provide an absolute url, as for instance:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
```

Note: As far as I know, the only place the tilde-slash is used in the context of Blazor is with the base element in the _Host.cshtml file

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference to just "/" or without?

Imagine your app lived in a folder, and you d onto know the name or it differs between installs.

/dev/
/prod/

YOu can not use / and you do not want to know the name at compile time.

ASP.NET MVC (NOT (!) Blazor, that happens earlier) puts in the root origin of the application folder as seen in the request and determiend at runtime.